# Noether's Theorem and Liouville's Theorem

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, noethers-theorem, phase-space

Liouville's theorem states that for Hamiltonian systems the phase space volume $V(t)$ is a conserved quantity, i.e., $\frac{d}{dt}V(t)=0$. This is related to the fact that trajectories in phase space do not cross and a point in phase space has a unique time evolution.

Noether's theorem tells us that conserved quantities correspond to continuous symmetries/cyclic coordinates, and vice versa.

My question is: what is the continuous symmetry/cyclic coordinate corresponding to the conservation of phase space volume?

Comment: $V$ is only a function of $t$, and has nothing to do with the phase space coordinates $(q, p)$?

Comment: @rschwieb It's the volume of a submanifold of the whole phase space, defined as an integral over phase space coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

There are several versions of [Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29)'s [theorem](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Advanced_Classical_Mechanics/Liouville%27s_theorem). One version states that a [Hamiltonian vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) (HVF) $X_H=\{H,\cdot\}_{PB}$ on a [symplectic manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M,\omega)$ is divergence-free
$$ {\rm div} X_{H}~=~0.$$
One may view the above HVF as the underlying symmetry.